# QT - Cmakelist - CLion - vtable doesn't compile

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, clion

I'm learning CPP and this weekend I learn more about QT, I'm using CLion and Cmakelist. I try to compile a project but when I add the macro Q_OBJECT it's say me :

undefined reference to `vtable for DigitalClock'
I'm looking for solved my problm and add AUTOMOC but it still doesn't work.

Is my CMakelist correct ?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7.2)
project(cpp_rush3)


find_package(Qt5Widgets REQUIRED)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -lncurses")
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC_ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

include_directories(Qt/widgets)


set(SOURCE_FILES
        ncurses/Curse.cpp
        ncurses/Curse.hpp
        ncurses/Panel.cpp
        ncurses/Panel.hpp
        Qt/window.cpp
        Qt/window.hpp
        main.cpp)

set(QT_SOURCE_FILES
        Qt/main.cpp
        Qt/widgets/cpu.cpp
        Qt/widgets/cpu.hpp
        Qt/widgets/monitor.cpp
        Qt/widgets/monitor.hpp
        Qt/widgets/date.cpp
        Qt/widgets/date.hpp
        Qt/window.cpp
        Qt/window.hpp)


add_executable(cpp_rush3 ${SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(qt_cpp_rush3 ${QT_SOURCE_FILES})


target_link_libraries(cpp_rush3 Qt5::Widgets)
target_link_libraries(qt_cpp_rush3 Qt5::Widgets)
```

Comment: Time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without the full errors and the code that caused it, this will be hard to answer in a definite way. All we can do is *guess*.

Comment: why do you compile those Qt cpp files ? you should only use the QT headers and link against Qt lib staticaly or dynamicaly.

Comment: Qt is only a folder of my project

Comment: This: `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC_ON)` should be `set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)` (space between a variable and a value).

Comment: This solved my problem I don't know how I don't see this but thank you, your awesome